# How can i solve the following integral?

Tags: integration

I need to solve, if possible, this integral that i found while working on a specific control problem.$$\int {\sqrt{1-a\sin 2\theta}}d\theta, $$being $$-1\leq a\leq 1.$$ Actually, the constant $a$ is given by $a=\sin\beta$, this is why $a\in[-1,+1]$. So far, i do not have any problem to analytically solve this integral when $a=1$. Any ideas will be absolutely helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: We get the following result: $$\frac{(a-1) \sqrt{\frac{a \sin (2 x)-1}{a-1}}
   E\left(\frac{1}{4} (\pi -4 x)|\frac{2
   a}{a-1}\right)}{\sqrt{1-a \sin (2 x)}}$$

Comment: When a=1 , $$1-2sin\theta.cos\theta=sin^2\theta+cos^2\theta-2sin\theta.cos\theta=(sin\theta-cos\theta)^2$$

Comment: Greetings friend. May I ask how did you solve it? What is $E$? Thanks for your help

Comment: Absolutely, when $a=1$, it is almost a trivial undergraduate problem. But what happens when, in general, $a\in[-1,1]$?

Comment: This integral is going to be a combination of Elliptic integrals.

Comment: Dear @DrZafarAhmedDSc would you explain me how please? Thank you